# Execute a windows command using java's Runtime package

Tags: java

this command works perfectly if I do it in the command prompt:

```
start Outlook /a C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\test.jpg
```

However when I try to execute it in java using the getRuntime().exec() method it gives me an error " Cannot run program "start": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified "

here is the code I am using:

```
 String command = "start Outlook /a C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\test.jpg";
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

not sure what I am doing wrong here. The start command is a valid command in the command prompt, I don't know how to get it to work with java's .exec() method

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` is not a program; there is no `start.exe`, it is just a shell command.

It's purpose is to start a program in a new command window. You'd have to use `cmd` to run that command:

```
String command = "cmd /c start Outlook /a C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\test.jpg";
```

But you don't actually need it here. Just do:

```
String command = "Outlook /a C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\test.jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

The command prompt is a bit different from what is done with `Runtime.exec`. `start` is a command that is provided by the prompt, but is not a real program. To make this work, you can invoke the prompt to run Outlook:

```
String command = "cmd /c start Outlook /a C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\test.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
String command = "cmd /c start Outlook /a C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\test.jpg";
```

you forget to call `cmd`, it will call the command prompt which will execute your command..